# Bluetooth button is enabled but bluetooth is not working

Tags: bluetooth

[Screenshot of my setting tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/se4BO.png)

You can see the image. There the bluetooth button is already enabled but it is still turned off. I have tried many solution available in the internet, but nothing works. Please help me because I really need the bluetooth. I am currently using a bluetooth 5.0 dongle.

Here is the output of hciconfig -a:

```
~$ hciconfig -a
hci0:   Type: Primary  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:14 acl:0 sco:0 events:1 errors:0
    TX bytes:3 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:1
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: PERIPHERAL ACCEPT
```

Here is the output of lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue :

```
    $ lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. Dell MS116 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[   18.761913] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   18.761928] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   18.761929] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.761931] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.761933] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.761935] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.217301] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[   24.388696] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Failed to suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[   29.508381] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (110)
[   32.421608] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   32.421612] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   32.421616] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[13466.369336] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[13471.396994] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Failed to suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[13476.516600] Bluetooth: hci0: setting interface failed (110)
```

Comment: Please share of the output of `hciconfig -a` on the terminal. Paste the text and format it rather than sharing a screenshot.

Comment: Please add output of `lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`

Comment: @Pilot6 output added

Comment: This noname dongle is a problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 I have added a new output, can you please check and give me any suggestion.

Comment: The device is `Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle`. It is a noname device with many problems. You can search the site for possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks @Pilot6. Finally I got solution. Reference: https://gist.github.com/mohclips/ad951c871ad77f451159eee51763d9a8

Comment: Write an answer then. It will be useful.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just followed the procedure of the above reference, which I have posted